# prove that : $\cos x \cdot \cos(x-60^{\circ}) \cdot \cos(x+60^{\circ})= \frac14 \cos3x$

Tags: trigonometry

I should prove this trigonometric identity.
I think I should get to this point :
$\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x $
But I don't have any idea how to do it (I tried solving $\cos(x+60^{\circ})\cos(x-60^{\circ})$ but I got nothing)

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the work you did so that we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: @Triomath, You can try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133590/evaluating-1-cos-frac-pi81-cos-frac3-pi8-1-cos-frac5-pi81/1133702#1133702

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sum of angles identity, 
\begin{align*}
\cos x\cos (x-60^{\circ})&\cos(x+60^{\circ})\\
      & = \cos x(\cos x\cos 60^{\circ}+\sin x\sin 60^{\circ})(\cos x\cos 60^{\circ}-\sin x\sin 60^{\circ})\\ \\
      & = \cos x(\cos^2x\cos^260^{\circ}-\sin^2x\sin^260^{\circ})\\\\
      & = \cos x\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos^2x-\frac{3}{4}\sin^2x\right)\\\\
      & = \frac{1}{4}(\cos^3x-3\cos x(1-\cos^2x))\\\\
      & = \frac{1}{4}(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Well How can I get to the answer by the last line?

Comment: You can use the identity $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3x - \cos x$ that you stated in the problem.

Comment: The identity is cos(3x) = 4cos^3 x - 3cosx isn't it?

Comment: @Triomath  You are correct.  Alijah made a mistake when he evaluated the cosine and sine of $60^\circ$.  He should have obtained $\cos x\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos^2x - \frac{3}{4}\sin^2x\right)$.

Comment: @AlijahAhmed You made an error in evaluating the cosine and sine of $60^\circ$.  Since $\cos(60^\circ) = 1/2$ and $\sin(60^\circ) = \sqrt{3}/2$, you should have obtained $\cos x\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos^2x - \frac{3}{4}\sin^2x\right)$.

Comment: @AlijahAhmed  Your last two lines still need to be corrected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. Yes indeed, I made a mistake. Many thanks for pointing it out - I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. $ \cos (x-60^\circ ) \times \cos ( x + 60^\circ ) = \frac{1}{2} ( \cos (2x) + \cos 120^\circ) = \frac{1}{2} \cos (2x) - \frac{1}{4}$
2. $ (\frac{1}{2} \cos (2x) - \frac{1}{4}) \times \cos x = \frac{1}{4} ( \cos (3x) + \cos (x) ) - \frac{1}{4} \cos (x) = \frac{1}{4} \cos (3x) $

Comment: @Triomath  This solution makes use of the identity $$\cos\alpha\cos\beta = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha + \beta)]$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$\cos (x-60^\circ )\cdot\cos ( x + 60^\circ )=\cos^2x-\sin^260^\circ=\cos^2x-\frac34$$

Now $\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$