# Proof expression:$\cos(80°)*\sin(70°)*\cos(60°)*\sin(50°)=\frac{1}{16}$

Tags: trigonometry, fractions

Proof expression:
$$\cos(80^\circ)\sin(70^\circ)\cos(60^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)=\frac{1}{16}$$

I tried in different ways, but I always get $\sin(20^\circ)$ in expression, which I can't simplify. What is the fastest way to prove this?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145406/prove-that-cosx-cosx-60-cosx60-1-4cos3x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cos80°\sin70°\cos60°\sin50°=\frac{8\sin20^{\circ}\cos20^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}\cos80^{\circ}}{16\sin20^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin160^{\circ}}{16\sin20^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{16}$$

Comment: How did you get to the second step?

Comment: I used $2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\sin2\alpha$ three times.

Comment: How did you simplify in the first step? That you got: $\frac{8\sin(20)\cos(20)\cos(40)\cos(80)}{16\sin20}$

Comment: $\sin70^{\circ}=\cos20^{\circ}$, $\sin50^{\circ}=\cos40^{\circ}$ and $\cos60^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How did you get sin(20°) in denominator?

Comment: Because it placed also in the nominator.

Comment: How did you get sin(160°)

Comment: $8\sin20^{\circ}\cos20^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}\cos80^{\circ}=4\sin40^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}\cos80^{\circ}=2\sin80^{\circ}\cos80^{\circ}=\sin160^{\circ}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, where could I learn to proof expressions this way, like you did. I tried to proof with addition formulas and I've written 2 A4 pages of simplification and still didn't proof anything.

Comment: You are welcome! Just solve math problems always and It will come.

Answer (score 1):

As @labbhattacharjee suggested, use the link with $x=20^{\circ}$ so that $$\cos(20^{\circ})\cos(-40^{\circ})\cos(80^{\circ})=\sin(70^{\circ})\sin(50^{\circ})\cos(80^{\circ})=\frac14 \cos(3\cdot 20^{\circ})=\frac18$$ Hence $$\cos(80^\circ)\sin(70^\circ)\cos(60^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)=\frac12 \cdot \frac18 =\frac{1}{16}$$ as required.