# Evaluating $\frac {\cos 81^{\circ}}{\sin3^{\circ}\sin57^{\circ}\sin63^{\circ}} $

Tags: trigonometry

> Find $$\frac {\cos 81^{\circ}}{\sin3^{\circ}\sin57^{\circ}\sin63^{\circ}} $$

This expression seemed quite easy to solve, but now the $63$ and $57$ in the equation are posing me with difficulties. I tried multiplying by $\cos9$ but I was unable to solve it further.

Would someone please help me to solve this question? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the angles in degrees?

Comment: Yes, they are in degrees

Comment: Is the correction so ok?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - x \right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + x \right) = \frac{1}{4}\sin(3x)$. Here $x$ is in radians.

Comment: @Dr Sonnhard Graubher Yes, thank you.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thanks a lot

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145406/prove-that-cos-x-cdot-cosx-60-circ-cdot-cosx60-circ-frac14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\alpha = 60^\circ$ and $\theta = 3^\circ$. The numerator is
$$\begin{align}
\cos(81^\circ) = \sin(9^\circ) &= \sin(3\theta)\\
&= \sin\theta\cos(2\theta) + \cos\theta\sin(2\theta)\\
&= \sin\theta(\cos(2\theta) + 2\cos^2\theta)\\
&= \sin\theta(2\cos(2\theta) + 1)\end{align}$$

while the denominator equals to
$$\begin{align}
\sin 3^\circ\sin 57^\circ \sin 63^\circ
&= \sin\theta\sin(\alpha-\theta)\sin(\alpha+\theta)\\
&= \frac12\sin\theta(\cos(2\theta) - \cos(2\alpha))\\
&= \frac14\sin\theta(2\cos(2\theta) + 1)\end{align}$$
This means the expression at hand equals to $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\frac{\sin 9}{\sin 3}
=\frac{3\sin 3-4\sin^3 3
}{\sin 3}
=1+2\cos 6= 4\sin 57 \sin 63 $$

Thus
$$\frac {\cos 81}{\sin3 \sin57 \sin63 }
=\frac{\frac{\sin 9}{\sin 3 }}{ \sin57 \sin63  }
=4$$

Answer (score 0):

Let x=3°, y=60°, rewrite expression as $\{\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\} \div \{\sin(y-x)\sin(y+x)\} $.

$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{3\sin(x)-4(\sin(x))^3}{\sin(x)} = 3 - 4(\sin(x))^2 = 1 + 2\cos(2x)$$

$$\sin(y-x)\sin(y+x) = \frac{1}{2} \{-\cos(2y) + \cos(2x)\} =  \frac{1}{4}(1 + 2 \cos(2x)) $$

Thus, expression simplified to 4